# Exporting a csv of pandas dataframe with LARGE np.arrays

Tags: python, pandas, deep-learning, export-to-csv, numpy-ndarray

I'm building a deep learning model for speech emotion recognition in google colab environment.
The process of the data and features extraction from the audio files is taking about 20+ mins of runtime.

Therefore, I have made a pandas DataFrame containing all of the data which I want to export to a CSV file so I wouldn't need to wait that long for the data to be extracted every time.

Because audio files have 44,100 frames per second on average (sample rate (Hz)), I get a huge array of values, so that
df.sample shows for e.g:
[df.sample for variable 'x'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GgCt.png)

Each 'x' array has about 170K values, but only shows this minimizing representation in df.sample.
Unfortunately, df.to_csv copies the exact representation, and NOT the full arrays.

Is there a way to export the full DataFrame as CSV? (Should be miles and miles of data for each row...)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a dataframe is not expected to contain np.arrays. As numpy is the underlying framework for Pandas, np.arrays are special for pandas. Anyway, a dataframe is intended to be a data processing tools, not a general purpose container, so I think you are using the wrong tool here.

If you still want to go that way, it is enough to change the np.arrays into lists:

```
df['x'] = df['x'].apply(list)
```

But at load time, you will have to declare a converter to change the string representations of lists into plain lists:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', converters={'x': ast.literal_eval, ...})
```

But again, a csv file is not intended to have fields containing large lists, and performances could not be what you expect.